# 2 server on same ip and port

Tags: redirect, iis, server, localhost

I want to run an application on an local IIS Server (same computer as request) and also global on intranet. They should be running both on the same port. If the global Server is running, the request get the answer there and if not, the local Server on the same computer is answering. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

network services will run on port numbers, For example, normally IIS uses port 80, and tomcat uses port 8080.

But of course you may change the port number of tomcat to port 80, but in the first place you need to stop the IIS service which is listening to port 80. Otherwise the OS will immediately complain and stop you from doing so.

So in your case, when you stop the global server, you need to start the local server (and vice versa).